# How use the parameters of an HttpServletRequest to make another one?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, resttemplate

I've an interceptor in Spring. This interceptor, if there is a special parameter in a request will do a request with slightly different parameters to the same host and manipulate the result.

The problem is that I used RestTemplate in this way:

```
   Map<String, String> paramsMap = new HashMap<>();
   paramsMap.putAll(request.getParameterMap());
   paramsMap.remove("unwantedparam");
   RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
   String result = template.getForObject(request.getRequestURL().toString(), String.class, paramsMap);
```

I paramsMap is the parameter map from the original HttpServletRequest, but rest template doesn't use it the way I thought... And anyway, this wouldn't work for POST. I'd ideally want this to work with any kind of request and be able to modify the request params

Is there a better way of achieving this? Even without using RestTemplate.

Comment: Non Spring way would be `Filter`s !

Comment: Yes, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Could you find a solution for it?

Comment: Nope, ended up doing it manually for the properties I needed!